# If $(X, || \cdot ||)$ is a normed vector space and A is a sequentially compact subset of X, is -A and/or A+y a sequentially compact subset of X?

Tags: real-analysis

$-A=\{-a: a \in A\}$ and $A+y=\{a+y: a \in A\}$.

I have an attempt for -A but not much for something like A+y. Take $u, v \in (X, || \cdot ||)$ and define $d(u,v)=||u-v||$. Then (X,d) is a metric space. (I show this just because we defined sequentially compactness for metric spaces explicitly) Now, let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of points of -A. That is, $x_n \in -A$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. So for all $x_n$, there exists $a \in A$ such that $-x_n=a$. Thus, $-(x_n)$ is a sequence of points of A, and thus has some convergent subsequence, say $-(x_{n_k})$ such that $-(x_{n_k})\rightarrow x$ for some $x\in A$. Since $x \in A$, $-x \in -A$ and so there is some $(x_{n_k})\rightarrow -x \in -A$ of $(x_n)$ of -A.

I think my last bit of logic isn't necessarily right. And I don't have much for A+y, but let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of points of A+y. That is, $x_n \in A+y$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. So for all $x_n$, there exists some $a \in A$ such that $x_n=a+y$. That is, for all $x_n$, there is some $a \in A$ such that $x_n-y=$. Take $(x_n -y)$ to be a sequence of points of A. Then there is a subsequence $(x_{n_k}-y)$ of A such that $x_{n_k}-y \rightarrow x$ for some $x \in A$. Since $x \in A$, $x+y \in A+y$, so $x_{n_k}-y+y \rightarrow x+y \Rightarrow x_{n_k}\rightarrow x+y \in A+y$. That is, there is a subsequence of a sequence in A such that the subsequence in A+y converges in A+y. Eh?

Comment: Your first argument seems fine to me. There is an assertion there that, since $-x_{n_k} \to x$, this implies $x_{n_k} \to -x$, but that seems fine to assert without proof, as you've probably covered something like this previously. Your second attempt needs a significant clean-up in its presentation, but yes, this is the general thrust. As an alternative, you could show that if $f : X \to X$ is continuous, and $A$ is sequentially compact, then $f(A)$ is sequentially compact. Then you just need to state that $f(x) = -x$ and $g(x) = x + y$ are continuous maps.

Comment: Ahhh alrighty, thank you so much for the help!